# ArrayList on forms in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm developping a app that allows to add lists of movies. I have a form when I want to put the information of the movies on the ArrayList. I want to add the data of movie in the form and then submit, and then other movie...

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formulario", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String addForm(Model m) {

            m.addAttribute("pelis", new ArrayList<Peliculas>());    

            return "addform";
        }

@RequestMapping(value = "/addpeli", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPedido(@ModelAttribute("pelis") List<Pelicula> pelis) 
            throws InstantiationException {

        peliculaService.addLibreria(pelis);

        return "added";
    }
```

Form:

```
<form th:action="@{/addpeli}" th:object="${pelis}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Nueva película</legend>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Título: </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{titulo}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Director: </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{director}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Sinopsis: </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{sinopsis}" /></td>
            </tr>
               <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I get the next error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'titulo' 
of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'titulo' is not readable or has 
an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type 
of the setter?
```

I understand that I can't to put the value of title directly in the form, but I don't know how to do it

**EDIT**:

Pelicula has a composite primary key.

This is my Pelicula class:

```
@Entity
public class Pelicula {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PkPelicula idPeli;
    private String titulo;
    private String director;
    private String sinopsis;


    public Pelicula(String titulo, String director, String sinopsis) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.director = director;
        this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
    }

    public Pelicula() {
    }

    //getters and setters
```

PkPelicula class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PkPelicula implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "id_libreria")
    private Integer idLibreria;

    @Column(name = "id_pelicula")
    private Integer idPelicula;

    public PkPelicula() {
    }

    public PkPelicula(Integer idLibreria, Integer idPelicula) {
        this.idPedido = idLibreria;
        this.idPelicula = idPelicula;
    }
```

Comment: attach full Pelicula class.

Comment: check this article : https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list

Comment: I have just added the Pelicula class @Alien

Comment: @tharanga-dinesh I found that article but it didn't work for me

Comment: @JaneC.are getter setter public?  please confirm. that is why i told you to attach FULL class.

Comment: yes, they are public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application will try to get property **titulo** from

```
List<Peliculas> -> List does not have this property so it will fail
```

If you want to bind property titulo for every item from the list, you must iterate all pelis elements in your thymeleaf and bind them to an input field:

```
<tr th:each="item, itemStat : *{pelis}">
     <td><input th:field="*{pelis[__${itemStat.index}__].titulo}" /></td>
     <td><input th:field="*{pelis[__${itemStat.index}__].director}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I found the problem few days ago, but you are right!